python classification using stratified labelling list
I have a stratified labels for categorizing games. Ideally I planned to use a final level to train my model and then fill back the earlier levels.
a brief example of the setup
genre          subgenre     
  Horror         Suspense
                 dark souls
  RPG            JRPG
                 1st person RPG
  platformer     metroidvania
                 2d platformer
                 3d platformer
  Shooter        1st person Shooter
                 3rd person Shooter

However, I ran into an issue when it came to training the model. my labelling is a bit sparse and as such sometimes games will jump different genre because of a label's affinity.
example is morrowind: ["1st person", "fantasy world", "combat"]. Training for Genre, it is able to identify RPG but training for subgenre selects 1st person shooter
Is there a way to use guide my training model to go down these trees or will I have to create a bunch of separate models based on the stratification? (as in each genre has a trained subgenre model)
code below:
def eval_and_print_metrics(clf, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
   print("Number of training samples:", len(X_train))
    print("Unlabeled samples in training set:", sum(1 for x in y_train if x == -1))
   clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    print(
        "Micro-averaged F1 scores:"
        % f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average="micro")
    )
    print("-" * 10)
    print()

    return clf

st_pipeline = Pipeline(
    [
        ("vect", CountVectorizer(**vectorizer_params)),
        ("tfidf", TfidfTransformer()),
        ("clf", SelfTrainingClassifier(SGDClassifier(**sdg_params), verbose=True)),
    ]
)

cate_to_model: str = "genre"
test_data: pd.DataFrame = test_dataframe[[cate_to_model, "keywordTags"]]

X_train_kd, X_test_kd, y_train_kd, y_test_ld = train_test_split(test_data["keywordTags"],
                                                                test_data[cate_to_model],
                                                                train_size=0.4)
my_model = eval_and_print_metrics(st_pipeline, X_train, y_train, X_test_kd, y_test_ld)

keyword_string: str = "1st person,fantasy world,combat"

prediction: np.ndarray = my_model.predict_proba([keyword_string])
classes: np.ndarray = my_model.classes_
prediction_dict: Dict = {}
for idx, cls in enumerate(classes):
    prediction_dict[cls] = prediction[0][idx]
    print("score: " + str(prediction[0][idx]) + "     " + "class: " + cls)   

I trained on the level 2 expecting the labeling to stay consistent when moving up to level 1 but instead it didn't work in this manner. I then tried to predict level 1 and then move down to level 2 but as level 2 was trained across all entries, it ended up reducing the score values and didn't work.
